# Python manage.py getting constant error in Visual Studio Code editor

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, manage.py

When I run anything in the Visual Studio Code terminal with 'python manage.py ...' I get the error below with "invalid syntax."

This happens with:

```
startapp 
migrate
runserver
```

etc., but only in the Visual Studio Code terminal.  When I run the exact same commands in the mac iTerm, they work just fine.  Why won't these 'manage.py' commands work in the Visual Studio Code terminal?

```
python manage.py migrate                                        
  File "manage.py", line 14
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Apologies, I should have added this - I've also tried it with python3 and get the following error:

```
python3 manage.py runserver                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and 
available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to 
activate a virtual environment?
```

When I test to see if the virtual environment is activated I get:

```
Shell for /Users/jp/.local/share/virtualenvs/blog-fvNRu8HW already activated.
No action taken to avoid nested environments.
```

Comment: Make sure you run it with python3

Comment: Please make sure about correct virtual environment.

Comment: Please see the section I added above.  I get a different error with python3 and it shows that the shell is already activated.

Comment: @jpanknin Did you solve this? using python3 does not fix it

Answer (score 1):

BEFORE you open the terminal inside VSCode you need to activate your virtual env for the current project.

So, once you have opened the project, then CMD (or CTRL) + SHIFT + P to open the Command Palette.

Start typing "Python" and choose "Python Select Interpreter"

[image]

You will see a list of python versions and environments:

[image]

Select the correct one for your current project.

Then open a new terminal and 'python manage.py ...' will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```